# Given a declarative SQLAlchemy class, how can I programmatically retrieve a list of its Column objects that are primary keys?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Say I have a class in SQLAlchemy like

```
class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'notes'
    slug = Column('short_title', String, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('day', Date, primary_key=True)
    contents = Column(Text, nullable=True)
```

Given only a reference to the Note class, how could a function build the list ['Note.slug', 'Note.date'] predicated on their constituting the corresponding table's primary key?

Furthermore, is there a way to filter class attributes based on column properties? (such as nullable, type, uniqueness, membership in an index, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to find the primary fields.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Date, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import InstrumentedAttribute


Base = declarative_base()

class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'notes'
    slug = Column('short_title', String, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('day', Date, primary_key=True)
    contents = Column(Text, nullable=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import inspect
    predicate = lambda x: isinstance(x, InstrumentedAttribute)

    fields = inspect.getmembers(Note, predicate=predicate)

    fields_vars = [vars(y.property.columns[0]) for x,y in fields]

    primary_fields = [x['name'] for x in fields_vars if x['primary_key']]

    print "All Fields :", fields_vars

    print "Primary Fields :", primary_fields
```

This way you can find any type of fields from your model.

Answer (score 4):

this will give you a list of column names which are primary_keys:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper

primary_keys = [key.name for key in class_mapper(Note).primary_key]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what's needed, but a bit shorter variant that's only using *inside* information:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Date, Text

Base = declarative_base()

class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'notes'
    slug = Column('short_title', String, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('day', Date, primary_key=True)
    contents = Column(Text, nullable=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print [(i.name, i.primary_key) for i in Note.__table__.columns]
```

This gives us following result:

```
[('short_title', True), ('day', True), ('contents', False)]
```